# Why does a TextView from a TableLayout not "update"?

Tags: java, android

I have a class that extends TableLayout, on which I have a TextView. It is correctly displayed for the first time when the constructor is called. Then I have a method inside this class that is as follows:

```
public class VerticalB extends TableLayout
  public TextView piece1
  ...
  public VerticalB(Context con){
    super(con);
    piece1 = new TextView(con){
        {
            setId(1);
            setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    };
  ...
  }

  public void Painter(double Angle, double InitAngle) {

    int FinalAngle = (int) (Angle - InitAngle);

    if(FinalAngle>0 && FinalAngle<10){
        piece1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
  ...
```

I call this method from another class and the parameters are passed correctly, and the *if* statement is entered when corresponds (I have checked), but my *piece1* is not coloured (or at least that is not showed in my screen).

It there a way to simply update the UI? If not, which other alternatives do I have (maybe override a method or do it as AsyncTask or runOnUiThread...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the declaration reference of piece1? I can only assume that is the TextView you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is. The declaration is above, I haven't posted the whole code as I thought it was unnecessary information but I will edit the question and add some things.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this? Change the TextView background color? Or any UI change?

Comment: I have solved. I infered from your question that, if really everything was okay, the color should change, so I have double checked everything and I have discovered that I was referring to the wrong object (I mean, the displayed object was one and the one that I was changing the color was another). This is due to the fact that the involved classes are several and I am still new to Android and I get a little bit lost when constructors with _Context_ are involved. Thanks you very much

Comment: Just for answering your question, what I am doing is receiving data from a sensor and displaying a bar that is proportionally "filled" (painted) to that data. The best way to imagine is a progressbar, but due to some special needs I am not using that element (maybe I will in the future, as the code I have now is really very unefficient). Thanks again!

Comment: dude, thats exactly why I asked you to post the declaration reference. I`m glad you did.